# Generating alphanumeric series

Tags: java, for-loop, logic

I am getting problem with generating a number based on the given number.   Actually I had to get series like `DAA001,DAA002,DAA003......DAA999` once `DA` series is filled with `DAA999` it has to generate `DAB001...DAB999` and once the series `DAB` is filled with  `DAB999` it has to generate `DAC001` to `DAC999` like that upto `DAZ001 toDAZ999`.

Here is my code please help me in this.

```
String start="DA";
String driv[]={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
String PrNumber="";
int  count=0;
if(driverprId<=999){
    count=0;
    start=start+driv[count];

    if(driverprId>=1&&driverprId<10){
        PrNumber=start+"00"+driverprId;
    }

    if(driverprId>=10&&driverprId<100){
        PrNumber=start+"0"+driverprId;
    }

    if(driverprId>=100&&driverprId<=999){
        PrNumber=start+driverprId;
    }
}

if(driverprId>999){
}

return PrNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i=0;i<driv.length;i++) {//for each alphabet
    for (int j=0;j<999;j++) { //iterate till 999
         start=start+driv[i];//keep using DA A if i is 0 for 999 times
         ...

        if (counter == number) {//number is like number of cells you need
            return;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me by using if condition ,if i use for loops sure i will get problem i don't want to genearate all records at a time,suppose if i give 134 it has to produce result as DAA134     If i give 26134 it should print result as DAB134 that's it no iteration for this ....

Comment: @user3528870 see my edited answer. number would be say 134 or 26134 that we are comparing counter with.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
String start="DA";
String driv[]={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
for(int i = 0; i < driv.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= 999; j++) { 
        String numbers;
        if (j / 10 < 1) {
            numbers = "00" + j;
        } else if (j / 10 < 10) {
             numbers = "0" + j;
        } else {
             numbers = "" + j;
        }
        PrNumber = start + driv[i] + numbers;
}
```

Condition only:

```
if (driverprId / 10 < 1) {
        numbers = "00" + j;
    } else if (driverprId / 10 < 10) {
         numbers = "0" + j;
    } else {
         numbers = "" + j;
    }
```

Comment: Please help me by using if condition ,if i use for loops sure i will get problem i don't want to genearate all records at a time,suppose if i give 134 it has to produce result as DAA134     If i give 26134 it should print result as DAB134 that's it no iteration for this ....